# Is it possible to use Pi's output signal as Arduino's input signal?

Tags: arduino-uno, raspberrypi

I have a relay attached to an Arduino Uno which I want to control using my raspberry pi 3b. And yes I know it can be done by attaching the relay directly to Pi but I cannot do so. Don't ask me why. That is why I want to know whether it is possible to use Pi's output signal as input for the Arduino or not. I do not have spare parts so I don't want to experiment. If anyone knows about this, please tell me.

Comment: What type of "signal" do you want? A simple pin, that can be set high or low from the Pi? Or a real data connection like Serial (UART)?

Answer (score 1):

This way is fine: the Pi is a 3.3V based board, so connecting one of the GPIO pin from the pi to an Arduino will not damage it. Furthermore, the 3.3V are sufficient to be considered as `HIGH` even on a 5v Arduino like the UNO.

The other way around: connecting the *output* of a 5V Arduino to the *input* of a pi, will very likely damage the raspberry Pi!

So beware of your Pinmode before doing such a connection!